# ChunkyPNG::OutOfBounds (Original image height is too small!)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, screenshot, watir, watir-webdriver

I am using git@github.com:ansoni/watir-extensions-element-screenshot.git
to take screenshot.

I am using a div id fetch screenshot, but the image inside is large when I am viewing (scrollbar appears to scroll the page to view the div completely).

I could view and download if the image size is small.

I am getting the following error when trying to capture screenshots of elements when the image is large (as it goes out of browser view):

```
ChunkyPNG::OutOfBounds (Original image height is too small!):
```

How to view and download the full image without scrolling?

My Sample Code:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new
    b.window.resize_to(1900, 1080)
    b.goto 'http://localhost:3000'
    b.div(:id => "phone_shell").screenshot("preview.png")
```

Comment: It would be useful if you can provide a page that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?